# Text on image hover in responsive grid

Tags: responsive-design, hover, center

I've made this responsive image grid. 
http://jsfiddle.net/ZhA6a/

```
<section class="project_main_container">
    <ul>       
        <li>
            <div class="project_container">
                <div class="project_media">
                    <img class="project_image" src="http://payload112.cargocollective.com/1/3/97886/4550499/2_800.jpg"></img>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>        
        <li>
            <div class="project_container">
                <div class="project_media">
                    <img class="project_image" src="http://payload112.cargocollective.com/1/3/97886/4550499/3_800.jpg"></img>
                </div>

            </div>
        </li>         
        <li>
            <div class="project_container">
                <div class="project_media">
                    <img class="project_image" src="http://payload112.cargocollective.com/1/3/97886/4550499/2_800.jpg"></img>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>         
        <li>
            <div class="project_container">
                <div class="project_media">
                    <img class="project_image" src="http://payload112.cargocollective.com/1/3/97886/4550499/3_800.jpg"></img>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>        
        <li>
            <div class="project_container">
                <div class="project_media">
                    <img class="project_image" src="http://payload112.cargocollective.com/1/3/97886/4550499/2_800.jpg"></img>
                </div>

            </div>
        </li>         
        <li>
            <div class="project_container">
                <div class="project_media">
                    <img class="project_image" src="http://payload112.cargocollective.com/1/3/97886/4550499/3_800.jpg"></img>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>      
    </ul>      
</section>

ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 0;
    }

.project_main_container {
    width: 100%;
    }

.project_container {
    float: left; 
    width: 33.3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333%;
    background-size:cover;
    overflow:hidden;
    }

.project_image {
    width: 100%;
    }

@media only screen and (max-width : 1000px) {
/*row of two boxes*/

.project_container{    
    width: 50%;
    }
}
```

Each picture represents a design case I've done. I want each image to darken and a text title to show in the middle of the image on hover.

I know that the effect I'm describing is existing but I can't get it working with the responsive grid.

I hope someone will help me - Thanks!

Comment: jQuery would be good for this

Comment: something like this? http://alijafarian.com/jquery-image-hover-captions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `:hover` with some CSS3 filters. The idea is to add your title as an absolutely positioned element within your grid blocks, and hide it by default. On `hover` the title will have a `display:block` applied to it so it appears. And the image will have a `filter:brightness` applied to darken it a bit.

**HTML**

```
<li>
    <div class="project_container">
        <div class="project_media">
            <img class="project_image" src="http://payload112.cargocollective.com/1/3/97886/4550499/3_800.jpg"></img>
            <h1>Project Title</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
.project_media h1 {    
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    width:100%;
    transform:translate(0%,-50%);
    -webkit-transform:translate(0%,-50%);
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-family:Arial;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    display:none;
```

}

```
.project_container:hover img {
    filter: brightness(0.3);
    -webkit-filter:brightness(0.3);
    -moz-filter:brightness(0.3);
}

.project_container:hover h1 {
    display:block;
}
```

And the working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/7hGPb/)**.

Comment: Thanks Brett! What if I want a colored overlay instead of black?

Comment: This is the same concept as mine except the image does not dim on all borwsers

Comment: Huangism - my demo was quick-and-dirty, I didn't include all the necessary browser prefixes. My method will also only work in browsers that support `filter`.

Comment: user3071765 - If can experiment with the `filter` property to get the desired effect. Or if you want to go total black-out you could set a `background-color` of #000000 and then change the `opacity` of the `img` element to 0 so it completely disappears.

Comment: Hey Brett,

Thanks you so much for your answers. As you can see I've implemented the solution in the bottom of this page of my portfolio: http://itu.dk/people/mbul/buch/project.html

How do I make it work in all browsers? I'm new to this coding-thing and making the necessary browser prefixes isn't one of my strong sides yet :-)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/ZhA6a/1/
No need for js. You can adjust the text position or colour as you like, this is just an example so you get the idea

```
<section class="project_main_container">
    <ul>       
        <li>
            <div class="project_container">
                <div class="project_media">
                    <img class="project_image" src="http://payload112.cargocollective.com/1/3/97886/4550499/2_800.jpg"></img>
                    <p>text</p>
                    <div class="dark"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>        

    </ul>      
</section>
```

CSS

```
p {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.project_media {
    position: relative;
}
.project_media .dark {
    display: none;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.3;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.project_media:hover .dark {
    display: block;
}
.project_media:hover p {
    display: block;
}

.project_media:hover img {
    opacity: 0.8;

}
```